# How to make exceptions when removing all children from a member of SKNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm looking for a simple way to make exceptions when removing all children from its parent Node.

Like: "Remove Tom, Ted, Tony,. but keep Lisa"

Comment: Please provide some code. What is this? A Array?

Comment: Your question is too short to give any answers, the best we can do is guess at your meaning. You need to include actual classes, some code you've tried, and so on.

Comment: I edited your question slightly, other than that I think this question is fine as it is.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the nodes having the `name` property different from `Lisa` and then removing them

```
self.children.filter { $0.name != "Lisa" }.forEach { $0.removeFromParent() }
```

### How could I add more names to the filter? ..like keep Lisa AND Tom?

```
let keepTheseNames = Set(["Lisa", "Tom"])

self.children.forEach {
    if let name = $0.name where !keepTheseNames.contains(name)  {
        $0.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I add more names to the filter? ..like keep Lisa AND Tom?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method, with Swift trailing closure syntax:

```
var children = ["Tom", "Ted", "Tony", "Lisa"]
var filtered = children.filter { $0 == "Lisa" }
// Now filtered contains only "Lisa"
```